# Checkbox does not update dependent value in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have a simple shiny app in which I choose a dataset, then I choose whether I will have quotes around character values or not and then I download the csv file. For some reason the app reacts only to my first default choice regarding the quotes (no quotes) and does not react when I click the checkbox in order to add quotes. If you open the csv file with a text editor you will see everytime:
[image]

instead of

[image]

when quotes are selected.

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for data download app ----
ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Downloading Data"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # Input: Choose dataset ----
      selectInput("dataset", "Choose a dataset:",
                  choices = c("rock", "pressure", "cars")),
      checkboxInput("quotes",
                    strong("Include quotes around values"), 
                    value = F),

      # Button
      downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")

    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      tableOutput("table")

    )

  )
)

# Define server logic to display and download selected file ----
server <- function(input, output) {

  # Reactive value for selected dataset ----
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$dataset,
           "rock" = rock,
           "pressure" = pressure,
           "cars" = cars)
  })

  # Table of selected dataset ----
  output$table <- renderTable({
    datasetInput()
  })

  # Downloadable csv of selected dataset ----
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste(input$dataset, ".csv", sep = "")
    },
    if(input$quotes==F){
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(datasetInput(), file, row.names = FALSE,quote = F)
    }
    }
else{
  content = function(file) {
    write.csv(datasetInput(), file, row.names = FALSE,quote = T)
  }
}
  )

}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying your `output$downloadData` generation to the following works:

```
 # Downloadable csv of selected dataset ----
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = paste(input$dataset, ".csv", sep = ""),
    content = function(file) write.csv(datasetInput(), file, row.names = FALSE, quote = input$quotes)
  )
```

This is also much easier to read and understand.

I am not sure, that your if-else "content" argument is interpreted correctly. I would have expected an error and I don't understand why it does not fail. If the `content =` was before the `if`, it might work. Anyway, in such a case, you should use the `ifelse` function or maybe do something like I have done above.

Also, the `filename` argument is also not needed to be a (lambda) function.

Finally, it is considered better practice to use `TRUE` and `FALSE` rather than `T` and `F` as the latter can be assigned variables.

The full script:

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for data download app ----
ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Downloading Data"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # Input: Choose dataset ----
      selectInput("dataset", "Choose a dataset:",
                  choices = c("rock", "pressure", "cars")),
      checkboxInput("quotes",
                    strong("Include quotes around values"), 
                    value = FALSE),

      # Button
      downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")

    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      tableOutput("table")

    )

  )
)

# Define server logic to display and download selected file ----
server <- function(input, output) {

  # Reactive value for selected dataset ----
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$dataset,
           "rock" = rock,
           "pressure" = pressure,
           "cars" = cars)
  })

  # Table of selected dataset ----
  output$table <- renderTable({
    datasetInput()
  })

  # Downloadable csv of selected dataset ----
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = paste(input$dataset, ".csv", sep = ""),
    content = function(file) write.csv(datasetInput(), file, row.names = FALSE, quote = input$quotes)
  )

}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```